# How to determine if a line contains a character in bash?

Tags: bash, unix

I would like to make a bash script that uses 2 arguments, `file1` `file2` that copies all lines from the `file1` that contains the letter `b` into `file2` . I have found the solution to determine if a string is contains the letter

```
if [[ $string == *"b"* ]]; then
  echo "It's there!"
fi
```

I just can figure how to apply this code to my problem, and run through each line of a random file.

In the course description i have found that this problem can be solved with the usage of `head -n` `tail -n` `cat` `echo` `wc -c` `wc -l` `wc -w` `if` `case` `test` , but we don't have to limit ourselves to the usage of just these commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the reason why `grep` has been invented:

```
grep "b" file1.txt >>file2.txt
```

(This copies all lines from `file1.txt`, containing the character `b`, to `file2.txt`)

Comment: It seems that I have overcomplicated the problem a bit, thanks